# Examples of inter process communication(IPC) in Windows

Tags: windows, process, operating-system

I am wondering about actual examples or instances of inter process communication (IPC) specifically for Windows, which we encounter on a daily basis (which happen under the hood or otherwise) while using our laptop/desktop.

For example:

```
Between a parent process and child processes?

Between two unrelated (in hierarchy) but cooperating processes?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple examples could be "Embedding a excel spreadsheet in a word document" and "Drag and Drop".